# 'Unable to prerender all routes!' Error Using Prerender SPA Plugin in a Vue Project

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, single-page-application

I am working on a project using Vue 3 and have encountered issues while implementing the Prerender SPA Plugin for prerendering. I'll detail my setup and the problems I'm facing below. What approach should I take to resolve this issue?

### problem

When using the Prerender SPA Plugin, I am encountering the error: '[prerender-spa-plugin] Unable to prerender all routes!'.

Error

```
> npm run build

> app@0.1.0 build
> vue-cli-service build

All browser targets in the browserslist configuration have supported ES module.
Therefore we don't build two separate bundles for differential loading.


⠦  Building for production...[prerender-spa-plugin] Unable to prerender all routes!


 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                                                                                                                     8:35:30

 error 

[prerender-spa-plugin] Unable to prerender all routes!

 ERROR  Error: Build failed with errors.
Error: Build failed with errors.
    at C:\Users\User1\OneDrive\dev\js\pages\src\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\commands\build\index.js:207:23
    at C:\Users\User1\OneDrive\dev\js\pages\src\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:157:8
    at C:\Users\User1\OneDrive\dev\js\pages\src\node_modules\webpack\lib\HookWebpackError.js:68:3
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\User1\OneDrive\dev\js\pages\src\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (C:\Users\User1\OneDrive\dev\js\pages\src\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:18:14)
    at Cache.shutdown (C:\Users\User1\OneDrive\dev\js\pages\src\node_modules\webpack\lib\Cache.js:150:23)
    at C:\Users\User1\OneDrive\dev\js\pages\src\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:1229:15
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\User1\OneDrive\dev\js\pages\src\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (C:\Users\User1\OneDrive\dev\js\pages\src\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:18:14)
    at Compiler.close (C:\Users\User1\OneDrive\dev\js\pages\src\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:1222:23)
    at C:\Users\User1\OneDrive\dev\js\pages\src\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:156:16
ode_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:18:14)
    at C:\Users\User1\OneDrive\dev\js\pages\src\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:498:23ode_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:18:14)
                                                                                           webpack\lib\Cache.js:122:37)
    at Compiler.emitRecords (C:\Users\User1\OneDrive\dev\js\pages\src\node_modules\webpack\                                               0), <anonymous>:6:1)lib\Compiler.js:919:5)                                                                     ode_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:1
    at C:\Users\User1\OneDrive\dev\js\pages\src\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:490:11
                                                                                           ode_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:18:14)
    at C:\Users\User1\OneDrive\dev\js\pages\src\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:885:14                                               0), <anonymous>:24:1)
                                                                                           lib\Compiler.js:919:5)
    at _next0 (eval at create (C:\Users\User1\OneDrive\dev\js\pages\src\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\User1\OneDrive\dev\js\pages\src\node_modules\tapable\e\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:24:1)
    at C:\Users\User1\OneDrive\dev\js\pages\src\node_modules\prerender-spa-plugin\es6\indexlib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:24:1:1).js:148:9                                                                                                                                 )
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

My `vue.config.js`

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("@vue/cli-service");
const PrerenderSpaPlugin = require("prerender-spa-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const Renderer = PrerenderSpaPlugin.PuppeteerRenderer;
const path = require("path");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  outputDir: "dist",
  assetsDir: "./",
  publicPath: "./",
  devServer: {
    open: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new PrerenderSpaPlugin({
        staticDir: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        routes: ["/", "/about-us", "/about-app", "/contact"],
        renderer: new Renderer({
          renderAfterElementExists: "#app",
          renderAfterDocumentEvent: "app-mounted",
          renderAfterTime: 1000,
          maxConcurrentRoutes: 5,
          ignoreJSErrors: false,
          headless: false,
        }),
      }),
    ],
  },
});
```

My `main.js`

```js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(router);
app.mount("#app");

app.mounted(() => {
    document.dispatchEvent(new Event('app-mounted'));
});
```

### environment

```
"@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
"@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
"@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
"@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
"@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
"eslint": "^7.32.0",
"eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
"node-sass": "^9.0.0",
"sass-loader": "^13.3.2",
"scss-loader": "^0.0.1"
```

### attempted solutions

- When Headless Mode is set to false: The browser displays the page correctly but remains in a perpetual waiting state.
- Changing renderAfterDocumentEvent and renderAfterElementExists: Modifying these results in the browser closing immediately, but the 'Unable to prerender all routes!' error occurs.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what that pre-renderer SPA library does, but it's had no code updates since 2019 - vue 3 was released in 2020 - is it even compatible with vue 3?